# Uniform convergence for $x\arctan(nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

I am to check the uniform convergence of this sequence of functions : $f_{n}(x) = x\arctan(nx)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R} $. I came to a conclusion that $f_{n}(x) \rightarrow \frac{\left|x\right|\pi}{2} $. So if $x\in [a,b]$ then $\sup_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x)- \frac{\left|x\right|\pi}{2}\right|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\to\infty.$ Now, how do I check the uniform convergence?

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n(x)-\frac{\left|x\right|\pi}{2}\right| = ?$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For $x\ne0$,
$$
0\lt\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\lt1\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, for $n\gt0$ and $x\ne0$,
$$
0\lt x\arctan\left(\frac1{nx}\right)\lt\frac1n\tag{2}
$$
For $x\gt0$,
$$
x\left(\frac\pi2-\arctan(nx)\right)=x\arctan\left(\frac1{nx}\right)\tag{3}
$$
Since $x\arctan(nx)$ is an even function, we can combine $(2)$ and $(3)$ to get
$$
0\lt\frac{\pi|x|}2-x\arctan(nx)\lt\frac1n\tag{4}
$$
Thus, $(4)$ says that $x\arctan(nx)$ converges uniformly to $\frac{\pi|x|}2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that 
$$\arctan t+\arctan\left(\frac 1t\right)=\frac{\pi}2$$
for all $t>0$ and that $f_n$ are even.