# Uniform convergence of $x\arctan(nx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$f_n(x)=x\arctan(nx)$; $n>=1$; $x$ belongs to $\mathbb R$. 
Prove that $f_n(x)$ uniformly convergent to a function $f$.
I have proved that $f_n(x)$ point wise convergent to $f(x)=(\pi/2)|x|$.
Now I need to find $\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ 
Any help...

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361439/uniform-convergence-for-x-arctannx?rq=1

Comment: Plz i need more details  than that answer

Comment: I added an answer to that question that is pretty detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Show that
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \frac{1}{n}$$

by using the formula
$$\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that $\lim \limits _n \sup \limits _{x \in \mathbb R} |f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$; equivalently, $\lim \limits _n \sup \limits _{x \in \mathbb R} |x| |\arctan nx - \frac \pi 2| = 0$. Since the function inside the $\sup$ is even (i.e. the graph is mirror-symmetric with respect to $0$), this amount to showing that $\lim \limits _n \sup \limits _{x \geq 0} x |\arctan nx - \frac \pi 2| = 0$. Since $\arctan y \leq \frac \pi 2 \forall y$, you get to show that $\lim \limits _n \sup \limits _{x \geq 0} x (\frac \pi 2 - \arctan nx) = 0$. Therefore, find the maximum of $g(x)=x (\frac \pi 2 - \arctan nx)$ on $[0,\infty)$ (it will depend on $n$) and see whether it converges to $0$ or not (use $g'$ and $g''$ to do this).